# Am I crazy? I think my stats professor is wrong about this simple probability question

Tags: probability

We are told that Shaquille O'neal's free throw percentage is 53%. We suppose he shoots a round of 30 and makes 18 of them.

*a) What is the likelihood that he made the first free throw?*

**My response:** This one is like drawing marbles (makes and misses) from a bag. For the first free throw, there's an 18/30 chance that he makes it. No need to incorporate priors.

*b) What is the likelihood that he made at least one out of his first 5 free throws?*

**My response:** We are already given the number of free throws that he makes in the round. Since ordering doesn't matter, all 30c18 combinations are equally likely. Of all of the combinations, there are 5c0 * 25c18 in which none are made in the first 5. We take this fraction (25c18)/(30c18) and subtract it from 1 to get the correct probability.

My professor disagrees and is doing something with the 53% prior, which I believe is not necessary. Please let me know if I am crazy in this belief.

Comment: Your responses reject what you have been told and use only the data from a single round. To justify your answers, then, you will have to explain why this limited dataset ought to supersede all other information.

Comment: Does you professor get different answers then yours?

Comment: @whuber: I disagree. We're not asked what will happen the next time Shaq tries a free throw. We're asked: given a set of 18 hits and 12 misses, where we don't know the order, what is the probability that the first shot was a hit? So it doesn't matter what Shaq's overall p(Hit) is. It's like asking: given that I threw ten 6's and a 5 with a fair die, what is the probability that I threw the 5 first? It doesn't matter that the die that produced this set of outcomes is fair. The outcomes are what they are, and now it's just a question of different ways they might have been ordered.

Comment: At what point in time are you making the prediction? Are you making the prediction before the 30 free throws on a day in which Shaq later made 18 of 30? Note that the probability that Shaq made the first free throw is either zero or one conditional on the outcome of the first free throw.

Comment: Be careful about using “likelihood”, as it has a particular meaning in statistics, even though “probability” and “likelihood” are synonyms in regular English.

Comment: @jkpate There is only one round of free throws (for which we do not know the exact indices of the makes and misses), and it has already happened.

Comment: @Ruben Your objection seems tangential to the question.  After all, at the point just before the first free throw in question a, *the new series of 30 shots has not even been observed.*  Nevertheless, question a makes sense and is answerable at that time based on the 53% figure.

Comment: You're not saying how your professor used a prior. Your assumption is that all orderings of hits and misses are equally likely, which may well be reasonable, but could also be completely false, who knows Shaq always hits the first 10 and misses the rest! Basically, there is not enough information to give an answer and extra assumptions need to be made. If we have prior knowledge that as the game progresses, players tend to hit or miss more, that can give a different answer than the one you got (using priors are otherwise).

Comment: I think this question is not well defined because the reader is given both the Truth and the data (which ought to be irrelevant if you already have the Truth). The reader has to then choose the degree that the Truth bears on her answers. Some version on this question makes sense for a Bayesian class, but I think this is either a poor question or a trick question.

Comment: It seems there are two sources of disagreement: what is the prior (a=0.53 or b=18/30=0.6) and are we estimating probabilities for (A) the round of 30 shots wherein he makes 18, or (B) for other shots for which we do not have a constraint on the shots made. It is a poorly-worded question because inferences about the round of 30 have a constraint while inferences about other shots do not have a constraint and because we have two possible probabilities of making a shot, one given and the other an estimate.

Comment: @whuber: We are interpreting the question differently. I interpret it as: the shots have already happened and someone has told us that 18 of them were hits. In support of this interpretation, the questions are all phrased in the past tense. The questions could perhaps be worded more precisely, but to me it seems clear that we're not meant to consider a new series of 30 shots, or to pretend that we don't know the number of hits yet. With the number of hits fixed, the 0.53 figure cannot play a role any more.